# Pandas truncates strings in numpy list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, truncation

Consider the following minimal example:

```py
@dataclass
class ExportEngine:

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.list = pandas.DataFrame(columns=list(MyObject.CSVHeaders()))

    def export(self):
        self.prepare()
        self.list.to_csv("~/Desktop/test.csv")

    def prepare(self):
        values = numpy.concatenate(
            (
                numpy.array(["Col1Value", "Col2Value", " Col3Value", "Col4Value"]),
                numpy.repeat("", 24),
            )
        )
        for x in range(8): #not the best way, but done due to other constraints
            start = 3 + (x * 3) - 2
            end = start + 3
            values[start:end] = [
                "123",
                "some_random_value_that_gets_truncated",
                "456",
            ]
        self.list.loc[len(self.list)] = values
```

When `export()` is called, `some_random_value_that_gets_truncated` is truncated to `some_rando`:

```py
['Col1Value', '123', 'some_rando', '456', '123', 'some_rando', '456', '123', 'some_rando', '456', '123', 'some_rando', '456', '123', ...]
```

I've tried setting the following:

`pandas.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 10000)`, but this doesn't change anything...

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent the truncation?

Comment: You made a numpy array of strings, so by default, it will use a fixed-length string `dtype` (which makes sense for numpy). Don't use a numpy array if you don't want that.

Comment: Is the whole point of the code to create a CSV? Why use *pandas and numpy at all*? Just use the built-in `csv` module. Or anyway, just don't use `numpy`. By default, strings with `pandas` use the `object` dtype which will allow for arbitrary-length strings. Just use pandas and don't involve numpy, or pass `dtype=object` when you create your numpy arrays. But it seems simpler to just use `pandas`, or even better, just use regular python with the `csv` module and you won't have to worry about things like this at all

Comment: I need it to create CSV, XLSX, JSON etc, which is why I picked pandas. But I may not need numpy though...

Comment: OK, I added an answer that should fix your problem at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `numpy` will by default choose a suitable, fixed-length unicode format.

Notice the dtype:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: values = numpy.concatenate(
   ...:     (
   ...:         numpy.array(["Col1Value", "Col2Value", " Col3Value", "Col4Value"]),
   ...:         numpy.repeat("", 24),
   ...:     )
   ...: )

In [3]: values
Out[3]:
array(['Col1Value', 'Col2Value', ' Col3Value', 'Col4Value', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', ''], dtype='<U10')
```

You should probably just not use numpy directly, but one quick fix is to replace:

```
values = numpy.concatenate(
    (
        numpy.array(["Col1Value", "Col2Value", " Col3Value", "Col4Value"]),
        numpy.repeat("", 24),
    )
)
```

with:

```
values = np.array(
    ['Col1Value', 'Col2Value', ' Col3Value', 'Col4Value', *[""]*24], 
    dtype=object
)
```

Notice the `dtype=object`, which will use just pointers to python `str` objects, so there won't be a limitation on the length of the strings

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I hadn't seen that numpy uses a fix-length string (presumably for efficiency reasons). Your answer works and has taught me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @GarethPrice yeah, basically, numpy is designed for fast, numerical computing on large multidimensional arrays. `dtype=object` essentially gives you a less flexible/performant Python list, so the API typically assumes you don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to your code which doesn't rely on numpy (and thereby avoids numpy's fixed-width unicode string type):

```py
@dataclass
class ExportEngine:

    def __post_init__(self):
        # changed in this example to use numeric column labels equal in number:
        #self.list = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(MyObject.CSVHeaders()))
        self.list = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(4 + 24))

    def export(self):
        self.prepare()
        self.list.to_csv("~/Desktop/testXYZ.csv")

    def prepare(self):
        values = ["Col1Value", "Col2Value", " Col3Value", "Col4Value"] + [""] * 24
        values[1:1 + 24] = [
                "123",
                "some_random_value_that_gets_truncated",
                "456"
            ] * 8
        self.list.loc[0] = values
```